# How to create start and end date buckets using windowed functions in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

I have a list of timestamps (WTIME), some value associated with that timestamp (VAL) and a category (WTYPE). There will only ever be one entry per timestamp. I need to transform the data so that I have 1 row per "grouping" of WTYPES.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (
    WTIME DATETIME,
    VAL FLOAT,
    WTYPE INT
)
INSERT INTO @TABLE 
VALUES
('2023-07-31 01:00:00', 10, 1),
('2023-07-31 02:00:00', 11, 1),
('2023-07-31 03:00:00', 12, 1),
('2023-07-31 04:00:00', 4, 2),
('2023-07-31 05:00:00', 6, 2),
('2023-07-31 06:00:00', 15, 1)
```

In the example here, there are three timestamps with WTYPE 1, it then switches to WTYPE 2 and then back to WTYPE 1 - so I would need an output of 3 rows (i.e. the 3 times it changed WTYPE) with the start time, end time, average value, WTYPE and number of rows.

[image]

I know this can be done with joining the dataset back onto itself but this method runs too slow for my purposes and I feel it in my bones that it can be achieved with windowed functions alone, I just cannot wrap my head around it!

Comment: @ThomA Seems like classic gaps-and-islands, which makes heavy use of window functions?

Comment: @ThomA Depends how you do it, it's actually more efficient often to *ony* use window functions, using `LEAD` `LAG`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could treat this as a classic gaps and islands problem and give each island a unique numbering and then group on that but the below can do it all in one scan ordered by `WTIME` so should be more efficient than that - [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/l7DcyQSD).

The idea being to calculate the cumulative sums and counts across the whole table, whilst preserving the last row from each island and look back at the previous such preserved row to calculate the diffs.

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT *, 
        MinWTime = MIN(WTIME) OVER (ORDER BY WTIME ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) ,
        CumeVal = SUM(VAL) OVER (ORDER BY WTIME ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) , 
        CumeCount = COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY WTIME ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) ,
        NextType = LEAD(WTYPE) OVER (ORDER BY WTIME),
        NextWTime = LEAD(WTIME) OVER (ORDER BY WTIME)  
FROM @TABLE
), LastInIsland AS
(
SELECT *,
       SUM_VAL = CumeVal - LAG(CumeVal,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY WTIME),
       NUM_ROWS = CumeCount - LAG(CumeCount,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY WTIME) ,
       START_TIME = LAG(NextWTime,1,MinWTime) OVER (ORDER BY WTIME) 
FROM T
WHERE NextType <> WTYPE OR NextType IS NULL
)
SELECT START_TIME,
       END_TIME = CASE WHEN NextType IS NOT NULL THEN WTIME END,
       WTYPE,
       AVG_VAL = SUM_VAL/ NUM_ROWS,
       NUM_ROWS
FROM LastInIsland
ORDER BY WTIME
```

Optionally you can simplify the execution plan somewhat by adding a dummy temp table with a columnstore index into the mix to get batch mode window aggregates. [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cIphlkEL)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using Tabibitosan technique to detect the groups:

```
select wtype, 
    min(wtime)  as start_time,
    max(wtime) as end_time,
    avg(val) as avg_val,
    count(*) as num_rows
from (
    select 
        wtime, val, wtype,
        row_number() over(order by wtime) -
        dense_rank() over(partition by wtype order by wtime) as grp
    from @Table 
) d
group by wtype, grp
order by start_time 
;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/sA2Jut_5

Comment: This does sort the data 3 additional times compared to my answer https://dbfiddle.uk/_Qnh7cZK (i.e. 4 times if no useful index on the table to avoid the initial sort or 3 times if we assume there is one)

Comment: I don't have a MSQL server running at hand right now, but comparing both versions on ORACLE, they both sort twice (no table, just CTEs so no indexes) (and a match_recognize-based version is sorting only once).

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/t7-Q94ny - My version has no sorts (uses the index order on `WTIME`) whereas this one has three. If the index on `WTIME` is removed then both have 1 additional sort as there is nothing available to provide that ordering https://dbfiddle.uk/wIDSI2P4